# How to find out the state (similar to Get-SPOSiteRenameState) while changing a site address, by http request

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Like already described in this post ([how to change a site address by http](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299822/change-a-site-address-url-by-http-request)), you can use a http request to change the site address of a sharepoint site instead of using powershell command *Start-SPOSiteRename*.

Changes to take up to 10min according to microsoft.
I need to know if the change is still pending, was aborted, or has been finished. When using powershell, you can use *Get-SPOSiteRenameState* to get states like : Queued, InProgress, NotStarted, Fail, Success...

I would need a similar call i can send as a http request.
I know you can check, if i site exists when using *sharepointurl/_api/web*.
So far it does return a wrong permissions error on me, when I do use this on the old sitename,
and would return success if the site exists.
Still, this does not give me the information i would like to have.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can do this via the following endpoint:

```
/_api/SiteRenameJobs/GetJobsBySiteUrl(url='{Identity.Url}')
```

I was unable to find any documentation for this endpoint but can see that it's being used in PnP PowerShell:

[RenameTenantSite.cs](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/src/Commands/Admin/RenameTenantSite.cs)

[Rename-PnPTenantSite](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Rename-PnPTenantSite.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the links :) 
This (get)-call helped me getting the queued rename-jobs with their current jobstate.

Comment: Glad it helped :)